# Итераторы подчиняются принципу чистой абстракции...

Tags: итераторы, c++

В принципе общее представление есть о том, как они работают, но в книге увидел это "Итераторы подчиняются принципу чистой абстракции, то есть любой объект, который ведет себя как итератор, является итератором", как это понимать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Судя по всему, имеется в виду следующее: любой объект, ведущий себя как итератор (то есть, как минимум, обладающий операциями разыменования (`*`) и продвижения (`++`)), может быть использован там, где ожидается итератор.

Это является по существу следствием ослабленной («утиной») типизации, применяющейся в шаблонах C++.

[Пример](http://ideone.com/UlK9iB):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename Iterator>
void print_container(const Iterator& from, const Iterator& to)
{
    bool first = true;
    for (Iterator it = from; it != to; ++it)
    {
        if (!first)
            cout << ", ";
        first = false;
        cout << *it;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    vector<int> v = { 11, 12, 13 };

    print_container(&a[0], &a[0] + (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])));
    print_container(begin(a), end(a));
    print_container(begin(v), end(v));

    return 0;
}
```

Указатель на `int` (`&a[0]`) вполне справляется с ролью итератора.

Comment: Спасибо! А ещё могли бы вы не по теме подсказать, почему в интервале (istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>())второй аргумент выступает в роли конечного итератора?

Comment: @Robert Pinkman: Ну, так решили разработчики стандартной библиотеки. Согласно [документации](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/istream_iterator):

> `istream_iterator()`: Constructs the end-of-stream iterator.